# Google analytics: disengaged users

Tags: google-analytics

Can I set up google analytics to track a number of unique users who completely disengage (don't visit the site at all) on a 90 days period?

Comment: I am confused. Google Analytics is specifically designed to track visitors of your site- How are you expecting it to track non-users who never visit your site??

Comment: Just wanted to set up tracking for anyone who's never visited the site in the past 90 days but who HAS visited before (and therefore is in our database). I basically want to put something in place in order to track disengagement over time.

Comment: I am not a GA expert at all. It would be a good tip if someone has an answer for you!! One up-vote just for that! If you have not done so already, check out Piwik. It is free and one of the very best user performance trackers.

Comment: This is more or less was the cohort analyses report does (measuring drop-offs), so you might want to look at that to see if this is already sufficient.

Answer (score 1):

There is a dropoff analysis report in Google Analytics which you can use but as with all other GA reports it is anonymous. The GA terms actually state that it is a violation to attempt to identify users based on GA records which are meant to be anonymous. The best way to do this and still stay compliant would be to setup a last accessed field in your database for each user and each time they log into the site add the datestamp. Then you can simply run a scheduled task regularly to run a query and get a list of users who haven't accessed the site in over 90 days and then you can do whatever you need to with the data, this would be completely compliant with GA.